# Retrieving headers for streaming object using AWS SDK for PHP (v3)

Tags: php, amazon-s3, http-headers, aws-sdk, aws-php-sdk

A [guide exists for v2](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/php/post/Tx2C4WJBMSMW68A/Streaming-Amazon-S3-Objects-From-a-Web-Server) of the [AWS SDK for PHP](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php) to stream objects, like an image, from S3. In that guide, it references `$command->getResponse()->getHeaders()` - both `getResponse()` and `getHeaders()` do not seem to exist in v3 of the SDK.

The [documentation for the stream wrapper in v3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/s3-stream-wrapper.html) makes no reference to retrieving the headers. I've tried the native PHP [`get_headers()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) with the `s3://` path, but that returns `false` (no errors). If I try `get_headers($fullurl)`, I am able to retrieve the headers.

How can I retrieve the headers for the object using the streaming path `s3://` for version 3 of the AWS SDK for PHP? Using the full URL will work for scenarios where I have private files.

Running some of the other native PHP functions that the documentation references do correctly return values using the `s3://` path. There might be a SDK method call for the headers, I just can't find it.

```
$s3->registerStreamWrapper();

$headers = get_headers('s3://my-files/' . $filepath);
//$headers === false

$headers = get_headers('http://my-files.s3.amazonaws.com/' . $filepath);
//$headers correctly retrieves all the headers
```

Answer (score 3):

**v2 code:**

```
$command = $s3->getCommand('HeadObject', [
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key'    => $key,
]);

$headers = $command->getResponse()->getHeaders();
```

**v3 code:**

```
$command = $s3->getCommand('HeadObject', [
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key'    => $key,
]);

$result = $s3->execute($command);
$headers = $result->get("@metadata")['headers'];
```

It's not quite a drop-in replacement. The array keys are lowercase now so you'll have to convert references like `$headers['Last-Modified']` to `$headers['last-modified']`

I couldn't find this in docs. I saw the examples using execute/results so I ran `echo $result` to look at the new structure and saw `@metadata`. It looks like this:

```
{
    .........
    "@metadata": {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "effectiveUri": "https:\/\/example.s3.amazonaws.com\/example\/file.txt",
        "headers": {
            "x-amz-id-2": "",
            "x-amz-request-id": "",
            "date": "Tue, 15 Oct 2019 20:04:18 GMT",
            "x-amz-replication-status": "COMPLETED",
            "last-modified": "Tue, 15 Oct 2019 19:08:28 GMT",
            "etag": "",
            "x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256",
            "x-amz-version-id": "",
            "accept-ranges": "bytes",
            "content-type": "application\/octet-stream",
            "content-length": "32213",
            "server": "AmazonS3"
        },
        "transferStats": {
            "http": [[]]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One solution doesn't seem like the most efficient way, but it works - it works off the fact that `get_headers($fullurl)` works.

Since we need to sometimes access private files, we can [get a presigned URL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/s3-presigned-url.html) that will give any user with the URL access, and run `get_headers()` off of that.

```
$s3getobject = $s3->getCommand('GetObject', [
    'Bucket' => 'my-files',
    'Key' => $filepath
]);
$presignedrequest = $s3->createPresignedRequest($s3getobject, '+5 minutes');
$s3url = (string) $presignedrequest->getUri();
$headers = get_headers($s3url, true);
```

Comment: `$headers = get_headers($s3url, true);` will not get all the information like content type.